# Opencart addToCart receives empty response

Tags: ajax, opencart

I have opencart. function addToCart() that adds products to cart works normal on normal pages.

I made custom page where I have just button that triggers function addtoCart(). Just normal button..

On normal page(where it works) I get normal response.

Please look at this link of images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtqcu.jpg

Third image is actually post that works OK, second picture is RESPONSE that works OK.
First picture is empty response which I get in custom page in open cart.

Do you have an idea why is this happening?

I use function addToCart() and use hard variable FOR TEST in that custom page, which means variables are always there to pass. I use hard variables so I don't have to explain how do I pass variables back in code(it works the same, it passes everything in debug). Problem is I get that "empty" response back only on custom made page. Response: [] ...

```
function addToCart() {

    var product_id = 79;
    var quantity = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For example if I want to use URL: http://www.ninetheme.com/tender/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add&productid=52&quantity=1 I get same empty response. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities to try

1. Using HTTPS to NON HTTPS or vice versa
2. Using www to non www domain or vice versa
3. Using a domain that isn't the same one as the one you're using to render the page

If none of the above are the issue, you'll need to work out what the exact differences are between the requests, though my guess is it's one of the three possibilities I've listed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I was adding a product without 1 needed attribute, therefore I always got empty response. There is an attribute in opencart where you have to setup to which store your product belongs. If you don't set that attribute if you are programatically adding a product into the store, you will add product, but you won't be able to add it to cart.